# Radio button to trigger Ajax call onClick

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have what is essentially a survey form. It's 17 multiple-choice questions. I want to use Ajax to save the answers and report a score as the user goes along. I.e.: When a user selects the radio button to select an answer to a question, it creates or updates the answer to that question in the database, calculates a score for all answers and displays in a div on the screen. All of that works fine when clicking the submit button.

Here is the form code

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod="post",
            InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId="currentScore"
        }
        ))
    { ... }
```

And each question has 5 answers linked to an answer id from a db table. I wrote code to add the answers to the database and update an on-screen score when the form is submitted, which **all works fine *when I click the submit button***, but I want this to happen each time the radio button for the specific answer is clicked.

**What I've done to attempt this:**

On the radio buttons I've added:`onclick="this.form.submit()"`

**Results:**

The form submits and as if it were not an Ajax form but like a normal form and the page reloads.

I have the following js on the page:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
```

**Here is the controller header (as requested)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.Net; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using PROJECTNAME.Models; 

namespace PROJECTNAME.Controllers { 

public class QuestionsController : Controller
{
...
```

The js is in a bundle:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Which is loaded on the layout:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Comment: how are you adding your script files in view code? probably the path is not correct for js files?

Comment: Can you show your controller header?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad The js files are being loaded properly, remember the button works properly. They are in a script bundle, which is  loaded on the layout with **@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")**: `            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));`

Comment: @lloyd I don't know how to make the comments show new lines, so this is going to be very unreadable... using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PROJECTNAME.Models;

namespace PROJECTNAME.Controllers
{
    public class QuestionsController : Controller

Comment: "Too broad"? I thought I was pretty specific. Pretentious pricks. I've heard people complain about that before here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to try if button works:

1) give form an ID or use the form tag to submit `onclick="$('#IdOfForm').submit();"`

2) find form tag on the page if single present `onclick="$('form').submit();"`

3) find the form parent `onclick="$('this').parents('form').submit();"` or another syntax finding a form tag.

4) Or just trigger the button click  `onclick="$('#IdOfSubmBtn').click();"`

So what I would put onclick event in function, and see what it is getting at each step. OR

Sometimes it need little delay because DOM is slow to pick up AJAX event. 
`onclick="setTimeout(function() { yours,1,2, or 3 }, 300);"`

Comment: #4 is the only one that worked. The others submitted the form, but not as Ajax.

Comment: Try setTimeout function above, it may help.

Comment: Is there a reason I shouldn't use the button click event? It does seem a bit like jury rigging, but if the other options aren't working...

Comment: There is no any reason, if code is doing what it was designed to do then all good!